# How to bind two or more model to p or span tag

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

How I can bind two or more model to single tag in angularjs.All I  want to do is to display full name by adding first name and last in span.i used two span tags to do this. Is it possible to add two model to one tag

```
<div ng-controller="mycontroller2">
    <table>
    <tr>
       <td><label>First Name </label></td>
       <td><input type="text" ng-model="firstName"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><label>Last Name</label></td>
        <td><input type="text" ng-model="LastName" /></td>
    </tr>   


    <tr></tr>
    <tr></tr>
    <tr>
        <td><label>Full Name</label></td>
        <td><span ng-bind="firstName"></span><span ng-bind="LastName"><span></td>
 <!--<td><span ng-bind="firstName" ng-bind="LastName"></span></td>-->


  </tr>
 </table>
</div>
```

Comment: use two way biding `{{}}` as  `<span> {{firstName}} {{LastName}}</span>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<span ng-bind="firstName + ' ' + LastName"></span>
```

OR

```
<span>{{firstName}} {{LastName}}</span>
```

OR

```
<span>{{firstName + ' ' + LastName}}</span>
```

You can use any angular expression with ngBind. You are not restricted to variable names.

reference: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBind

Answer (score 3):

> The ngBind attribute tells Angular to replace the text content of the
>   specified HTML element with the value of a given **expression**, and to
>   update the text content when the value of that expression changes.

```
<span ng-bind="firstName + ' ' + lastname">
```